# How to write a forEachRight-function, that is working with objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the exercise to write the forEachRight-Function by myself:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEachRight

When the collection is an array it's easy. I just loop through it in the reversed order:

```
_.forEachRight = function(list, callback) {
if(Array.isArray(list)) {
for (let i = list.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
    callback(list[i], i, list);
}
else {
  
}
}
```

But how to solve it, if the collection is an object give me real big problems and minor bugs.

This is an example object:

```
 var brothers = {
    Toby: 23,
    Max: 24,
    John: 25
}
```

I tried to solve it with unshift and add it to an array:

```
_.forEachRight = function(list, callback) {
    let reverseArray = []
    if(Array.isArray(list)) {
    for (let i = list.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
        callback(list[i], i, list);
    }
    else {
    for (var key in list)
    {reverseArray.unshift(callback(list[key], key, list))}
    }
    console.log(reverseArray);
    }
```

The `console.log` is just for my testing.

Now I could easily loop through reverseArray with a for loop. Also it is also possible to either loop through the properties:

```
_.forEachRight(brothers, function(value, name, list) {
    return name;
})
```

Or through the keys:

```
_.forEachRight(brothers, function(value, name, list) {
        return value;
    })
```

BUT: if I use `console.log(value)` or `console.log(name)` in the return of the callback function:

```
_.forEachRight(brothers, function(value, name, list) {
    return console.log(value);
})
```

it is not working anymore.

Output:

```
23
24
25
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Then I tried to "fix" the loop by using `unshift(list[key], key, list)`.

But then it is always unshifting everything to the reverse array and not only what I returned in the callback function (which is logical).

Now I am stuck and a bit confused how the library solved this problem? Or did they wrote a lot of if-statements to exclude so special cases like `return console.log`. This would be my last solution, but I thought maybe there is an easier solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem... What is destroyed and how? Can you show a reproducible example?

Comment: What is `reverseArray` supposed to do here? AFAIK, in forEach, the return value of the callback is ignored (unless lodash does something special for forEachRight).

Comment: Why do you use the return value of the callback? Why not first adding the values to the reverse array and later looping over that and calling the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` to get an array of keys and values. Then you can call yourself recursively with that array.

```js
forEachRight = function(list, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(list)) {
    for (let i = list.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
      callback(list[i], i, list);
  } else {
    forEachRight(Object.entries(list), ([key, value], _, __) => 
      callback(value, key, list));
  }
};

forEachRight({
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}, (v, k) => console.log(k, v));
```